# Find overlapped date ranges and add corresponding performance metrics to measure efficiency

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

```
+----------+------------------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+
|  Name    |  Booking Type    |  Job  | Loading | Start Date  |  End date  |
+----------+------------------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+
| John     | Chargeable       | job1  |      20 | 04/11/2019  | 31/01/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job2  |     100 | 01/10/2019  | 31/12/2019 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job3  |     100 | 14/10/2019  | 01/11/2019 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job6  |      50 | 29/07/2019  | 30/09/2019 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job7  |      50 | 29/07/2019  | 30/09/2019 |
| John     | Vacation/Holiday | job8  |     100 | 10/01/2020  | 10/02/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job9  |     100 | 23/03/2020  | 30/07/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job10 |      50 | 20/01/2020  | 20/03/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job11 |      20 | 03/02/2020  | 20/03/2020 |
| John     | Chargeable       | job12 |      30 | 22/01/2020  | 20/03/2020 |
| Kimberly | Chargeable       | job11 |      20 | 03/02/2020  | 20/03/2020 |
| Kimberly | Chargeable       | job13 |     100 | 22/01/2020  | 20/03/2020 |
| Kimberly | Chargeable       | job14 |     100 | 22/04/2020  | 20/04/2020 |
+----------+------------------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

For each row, I am trying to find if the job date range overlaps with other Jobs. If there is an overlap I want to sum the loading amount for all the overlapped jobs.

This is what i tried, created a new column in the table:

```
loading Status =
VAR staffname = 'Staff Booking'[Name ]
VAR jobstart = 'Staff Booking'[Start Date].[Date]
VAR jobend = 'Staff Booking'[End Date].[Date]
VAR bookingtype = 'Staff Booking'[Booking Type ]
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Staff Booking'[Loading] ),
            FILTER ( 'Staff Booking', 'Staff Booking'[Name ] = staffname ),
            FILTER ( 'Staff Booking', 'Staff Booking'[Booking Type ] == "Chargeable" ),
            FILTER (
                'Staff Booking',
                'Staff Booking'[Start Date].[Date] <= jobend
                    && jobstart <= 'Staff Booking'[End Date].[Date]
            )
        ) > 100
            && bookingtype = "Chargeable",
        "Overbooked",
        "Normal"
    )
```

However, this code misses out on this particular case:

[image: Gantt chart view of a sample timeline]

The dark blue means the job is overloaded(>100) according to the DAX formula above, and the light blue means the job is Normal (100).

However the dark blue(first and second) here are not correct, because they never get more than 100 at any period of time. The reason why they are marked as overloaded is that the Dax formula is combining the loading for all the different time period that overlaps.

e.g. Job 12 = Job 12 + Job 10 + Job 1 + Job 20 = 120

which is wrong because Job 12 is always 100 at any time period

e.g.  Job 12 = Job 12 + Job 10 + Job 1 = 100

and Job 12 = Job 12 + Job 10 + Job 20 = 100

1) Is there a way to tweak the DAX formula or any other method to ensure it rectifies the above so that Job 12 should not be considered overbooked in the above scenario

2) As a side effect of rectifying the scenario above, there comes a case where

**if** `Job 20` **loading is set to 50**,

then Job 12's loading sum will see two different phases:

Phase 1) Job 12 =  Job 12 + Job 10 + Job 1 = 100 (normal)

Phase 2) Job 12 =  Job 12 (30)+ Job 10 (50) + Job 20 (50) = 130 (overbooked)

In this case the DAX formula should take the highest Phase and put in the column "Overbooked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier if you use a calendar table. For example, you can calculate the load for a selected `Name` like this:

```
Load =
VAR ThisDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( Dates[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Booking[Loading] ),
        FILTER (
            Booking,
            Booking[Start Date] <= ThisDate &&
            Booking[End date] >= ThisDate &&
            Booking[Booking Type] = "Chargeable"
        )
    )
```

Here's a visualization of this with `Dates[Date]` on the x-axis and `Load` for Values.

[image: Load Example]

Now since this is calculated for each `Dates[Date]` separately, your loading status shouldn't overlap like you had and the measure can be as simple as:

```
loading Status = IF ( [Load] > 100, "Overbooked", "Normal" )
```

---

**Edit:**

To do this as a calculated column, you need to look at each day during the job and see if the `[Load]` goes over `100`:

```
LoadingStatus =
VAR TempTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            Dates,
            Dates[Date] <= Booking[End date] &&
            Dates[Date] >= Booking[Start Date]
        ),
        "DayLoad", CALCULATE ( [Load], ALLEXCEPT ( Booking, Booking[Name] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( MAXX ( TempTable, [DayLoad] ) > 100, "Overloaded", "Nomral" )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. The main goal why i am trying to do this is that i am showing all my employee job timelines on a gantt chart. Having the loading status for all the jobs in a nother column is preferrable as that can be used in various places to e.g. the gantt chart bar color can be set to different color for the jobs that are overloaded/underloaded and normal by using that column as a reference

Comment: See if my edit helps. It still uses the `[Load]` measure already defined.

Comment: I tried to attemp testing this solution but i have no idea where are you getting `Dates[Date] `  or `Dates` i dont have such column in my table, what column should i insert in the slicer. Quite a newbie and working my way around Power Bi, could you please upload the pbix you are using

Comment: Pls disregard previous comment, your solution works perfectly, will check if it fails for edge cases thank you!